# ASP.NET MySql Membership Move Database to new machine issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, mysql

I am trying to move an old ASP.NET application to a new server.

The app is setup with mysql membership/role providers.

I can get to the login page on the new server (uses ASP.NET Login component) but I cannot get passed the login screen. The first time I enter the credentials I get put back to the Login page without any message. If I try again with the same details I get 'Login Failed'.

The membership table does record a successful login.

In my dev env if change the web.config to point to the old MySql server it works fine. Point it to the new database and I get the issue.

Are there any MySql server specific key/values being used somewhere?

I realise that these are pretty old version but -

- Using MySql connector 5.2.7.0
- Current database: 5.1.49 community
- New database: 5.1.63 Community
- .NET Core 3.5.0

web.config membership:

```
<add connectionStringName="golfmannenConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
             autogenerateschema="true"
             enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             applicationName="/GM2008" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="MySQLMembershipProvider" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
```

Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".gmLOGINcookie" loginUrl="~/FormsPublic/Login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="~/Forms/Home/Default.aspx" />
  </authentication>
```

I really dont know where to look further. Anybody help?
Thanks
Jon

Comment: does your web server have permission to login to the new mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using encrypted passwords?  This uses the  value from that machine to hash the passwords created.